# Drawing app - intellisense error

Tags: graphics, c++-cli, intellisense

so im making a drawing app and i have a last error - intellisense. This is the error:

```
IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "System::Drawing::Graphics::DrawLine" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (System::Drawing::SolidBrush, System::Drawing::Point, System::Drawing::Point)
            object type is: System::Drawing::Graphics
```

This is the code/ line:

```
g->DrawLine(SolidBrush(colorSel), oldPosition, e->Location);
```

Comment: This is not standard c++. It is managed c++. I changed the tag to `c++-cli`

Comment: You're getting an IntelliSense error on that line... When you compile, do you get a compile error on that line?

Comment: David, yes. The error is from the certain line of the code i copied here.

Comment: You draw a line with a pen, not a brush.  Pass `%Pen(colorSel)` instead.